# Stop linux bash script when a background job fails

Tags: bash, error-handling, background-process

How to be noticed when a background job failed (through any signal SEGV, ABRT, KILL, INT ...), *when the job is in the background* in a linux bash script.

```
set -e
foo &
foo_pid=$!
# Do tasks that requires that foo is running
wait $foo_pid
```

does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can help

```
set -e
foo &
foo_pid=$!

# If this script is killed, kill the `cp'.
trap "kill $foo_pid 2> /dev/null" EXIT

while kill -0 $foo_pid 2> /dev/null; do
    # Do smth
    ...
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: So you basically checks that the process still exists for every command? If a command requires that it exists, you would wrap it with that loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch the signal and update to a file with time and date.

```
set -e
act() { 
  echo "Caught signal!" > /tmp/file.txt
  echo `date` >> /tmp/file.txt
  exit
}

trap act SIGINT SIGTERM SIGKILL

foo &
foo_pid=$!
# Do tasks that requires that foo is running
wait $foo_pid
```

Comment: The problem is that the trap is not trigged.